# Select query on two tables with fuzzy matching

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables - 'brands' & 'phones' as illustrated in the sqlfiddle below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6da79

```
brands(id, brand) 
phones(id, brand_id, phone)
```

I basically want to know how to best implement a search that will do the following - if a user enters 'Sony Ericcson' - it displays all the phones from that brand.. however if they enter the search term 'Sony Ericsson Xperia' it will be clever enough to do a LIKE and retrieve the single phone called 'Xperia P'.

I can understand the logic - just trying to find the best optimised way to do this with the smallest footprint on the database.

My pseudocode would look as follows:

1. Do a LIKE query on the brands table from search keyword term (e.g Sony)
2. If a match is found display all phones from that brand (e.g Xperia P, W500)
3. If the user enters 'Sony Ericsson Xperia' - we will want to remove the 'Sony Ericsson' from the query and just do a like query on 'Xperia' and return the 'Xperia P'

Can anyone recommend the most optimised method of doing this?

Comment: this problem is quite "nontrivial". Despite the marketing hype, computers aren't "smart". In fact, they're quite dumb and can't easily notice implicit patterns (i.e. i think it will require a very nice algorithm to derive "Xperia P" from "Sony Ericsson Xperia"

Comment: select p.phone from phones p
inner join brands b
on(p.brand_id = b.id)
where b.brand = "Sony Ericcson"
and p.phone like "%Xperia%"

Comment: @STTLCU i've got a brand_id which is the foreign key in the phones table that links to the brands table.

Comment: nevertheless, the algorithm should take into account that there are a lot of words, that may be in random order (what's the result of "Iphone apple 5s gold" for example?) or conflicting or wrongly spelled or whatever. Google's "were you looking for...?" algorithm is the result of years of research :)

Comment: @RobertRozas the point isn't the query itself, but it's about recognizing which token has to go in which part of the where condition. How would you recognize "Xperia P Sony Ericsson" vs. "Sony Ericsson Xperia P" vs. "Sony Xperia" etc?

Comment: You might want to offer the user two text boxes, one for brand and one for model.  If fact, you could use related selects if you don't have that many brands.

Comment: Depending on the scale of the project, you may want to consider full text searching with [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)

Comment: @AlexP heh, I was gonna mention that ... but Solr instead to take some of the grunt work out ;) : http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcb807

Basically used the following method as advised - see the sqlfiddle and use another table for doing the queries linked up with the id of the phones table. I hope it makes sense :-) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you should use fulltext search just like

```
    select * from brands b join phones p
    on p.brand_id = b.id
    where match (b.brand, p.phone)
    against ('sony ericsson xperia' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but it's only work in myIsam engine (:

[check](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Just remember to add a FULLTEXT index on the field as well ;)

Comment: Even if he's using InnoDB, he can create a separate MyIsam table that houses the text data and relevant id's.

Comment: I think that might be the way to go.. i'll give it a shot & see how i get on

Comment: Should i just make 2 further tables for the brands & phones - call them brands_fulltext, phones_fulltext - use the same fields as the the brands & phone tables but change it to MyISAM and put a fulltext on the fields searchable (in this case the brand name & phone name)

Comment: it could be just change it to MyIsam and put the fulltext index,
but you will lost the foreign key constraint between them,
in other scenario, you can add a table in InnoDb that create their relationship
p.s sorry for my english (:

Comment: @wortel thanks mate - your english is perfectly fine thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to join the two tables and concatenate brand name and phone name. Then match against this concatenated string:

```
select *
from brands
join phones on (phones.brand_id = brands.id)
where concat(brands.brand, ' ', phones.phone) like concat('your search string here','%')
```

This complies with your request. In spite of that be aware that this is still a very poor search engine. The search string must match exactly. 'Sony' does, 'Sony Ericsson' does, 'Sony Ericsson Xperia' does, even 'Sony E' does, but 'Sony  Ericsson' (two blanks) doesn't, and 'Sony Xperia' doesn't either.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to do a join. Try something like:​

```
SELECT phones.id, phones.phone, brands.id, brands.brand 
FROM brands, phones  
WHERE brands.brand LIKE 'Sony Ericsson' AND brands.id = phones.brand_id;
```

You could always adjust the above with an OR to search for a phone name too.